# Menus not clickable on iPad/iPhone

Tags: html, css, ipad, hyperlink, html-lists

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to create a menu. Simple run of the mill html/css stuff.
Having problems when on the iPad - some of the links don't work.
The dropdown menu is working fine - as are all the links within - which seems strange. There's a "scroll-to" function on the list - might be the problem but it's not affecting the dropdown? Sort of stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Can be seen here.
http://www.lapthelough.org/index.php/lap10

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul id="scrolling" class="nav nav-pills">
           <li class="active menubadge float shadow" ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#event" class="float shadow">event</a></li>
            <li><a href="#route" class="float shadow">route</a></li>
             <li><a href="#start" class="float shadow">start</a></li>
            <li><a href="#safety" class="float shadow">safety</a></li>
            <li><a href="#partner" class="float shadow">partner</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fund" class="float shadow">fundraise</a></li>
            <li><a href="#register" class="float shadow">register</a></li>


           <!-- dropdown in main menu "DROPNAV"-->
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">&hellip; <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Social</li>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/lapthelough">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/lapthelough">Twitter</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I've removed the CSS3 classes .float and .shadow and the links now work.
Not entirely sure why these would interfere with the link?

again - any help appreciated.

Comment: It looks like there may be some conflict with the CSS already built into Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I've had issues similar in the past and oddly enough it was just that there was a transparent `div` that covered part of the menu when displaying on iPad. Any chance it could be something like that? Simple fix with `z-index`?

Comment: Just saw your comments above. Any chance of showing the CSS for `.float` and `.shadow`?

Comment: I'm using: http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/index.html#

Comment: To be honest it's easier to drop these on links than concoct some elaborate workaround. Links are links, no real need to add much to them - I'll know for again not to use them with Bootstrap.